# Find invariant points, how to express using parameter

Tags: matrices, transformation

I have a matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}$$

where I have to find the invariant points for a transformation using this matrix.

I have no problem working through to two equations y = -x which means that the invariant points are all points on line y = -x (y + x = 0).

But question asks for co-ordinates to be expressed as parameter so I expressed my answer as:

$$(-\lambda, \lambda)$$

But book answer shows:

$$(\lambda, -\lambda)$$

Was I wrong?  Is there a convention to show x co-ordinate as the positive if corresponding why opposite sign???

OK, so I was thinking that maybe they are equivalent until I looked at the next question: matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix}0.6&0.8\\0.8&-0.6\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\frac{3}{5}x + \frac{4}{5}y = x$$

$$3x + 4y = 5x$$

$$4y = 2x$$

$$y = \frac{1}{2}x$$

and

$$\frac{4}{5}x - \frac{3}{5}y = y$$

$$4x - 3y = 5y$$

$$4x = 8y$$

$$y = \frac{1}{2}x$$

This then gives you two equations same: $$y = \frac{1}{2}x$$

So when x = 1, y = 2

So I expressed as:

$$(\lambda, 2\lambda)$$

But book shows:

$$(2\lambda, \lambda)$$

Is the book wrong?

If the book is correct then what is the explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, you and the book gave the same answer. When you express something parametrically, you can "change the speed" of the parameter:
$$\{(\lambda, -\lambda)\ :\ \lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
is the set of all the points of that form obtained by letting $\lambda$ run through all the real numbers; if you write
$$\{(-\lambda,\lambda)\ :\ \lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
you are just "enumerating" the elements in a different way, but you end up with the same collection (set) of elements… to obtain, e.g., $(1,-1)$, you have to set $\lambda=1$ in the first case, $\lambda=-1$ in the second.
You could have also written
$$\{(2\lambda, -2\lambda)\ :\ \lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
or
$$\{3\lambda-1, 1-3\lambda)\ :\ \lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
or, as long as you don't want to do any more linear algebra with such a result
$$\{(\lambda^3, -\lambda^3)\ :\ \lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}\;.$$
All these sets are the same, simply described in different ways.

Now, for your second question, you solved the last equation incorrectly:
$$y=\frac12 x$$
means that the $y$ is half of the $x$ … so $x=1$, $y=1/2$ is a solution and *not* $x=1$, $y=2$.
In generale, set $x=\lambda$ and work out the value for $y$ … or the opposite, if computations seem easier this way.
If $x=\lambda$, $y=\lambda/2$, so $\{(\lambda, \lambda/2)\ :\ \lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is your set of points, which can be equivalently described by
$$\{(2\lambda,\lambda)\ :\ \lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
(you find this second form if you set $y=\lambda$ and find $x$ from the equation, in terms of $\lambda$).

Answer (score 0):

When $x=1$, then $y=\frac{1}{2}$. Whatever the value of $y$ is, $x$ is twice that so the book is correct.